# Vertically Aligning Flexbox Items Correctly

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am working on creating a footer for my app where there are 3 main components. The current footer container is:

```css
.footer-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $bar-color;
```

Each child element has

```css
display: inline-block
```

And it produces the vertical alignment that I am looking for:

[image]

However, I am looking to center the 3 components equally across the footer. The flexbox `space-between` option looked like it would fit best, therefore I tried it. In terms of horizontal alignment, it is perfect, however when I add

```css
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

to the `footer-container` class it moves the first item down. Like this:
[image]

I'm not sure why this is occurring. How would I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the html ??

Answer (score 1):

A flexbox has two main axes. You are aligning items along one axis of the flex container with `align-items`, but you also need to include the `justify-content` property for aligning along the other main axis of the flex container. That is why you see the uneven row.

When you specify both axes of the container with CSS properties `justify-content` and `align-items`, using `space-between` works as expected. [Flexbox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #111;
}

:root {
  --footer-color: #000;
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--footer-color);
}

.footer-container p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="footer-container">
      <p>Connected</p>
      <p>12:00:59 AM</p>
      <p>Version 0.0.1 (Latest Version)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```